# Why won't this jQuery include work?

Tags: jquery, window, lightbox, modal-dialog

I have a modal window from which I am calling a lighbox to view images. I have got the lightbox to work on it's own, but cannot get it working from the modal window.

If i include jQuery before the lightbox includes - the page breaks and all styling of the portlet fails.

Any help greatly appreciated, Rich.

Project: http://djrb.co.uk/lightbox/tester.html

Working example of lightbox: http://djrb.co.uk/lightbox/working_example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are including both jQuery and Prototype.  Since they both redefine the $ you need to do special handling and have the following line after jQuery is loaded

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
```

See [this link](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have just added this code, and the example still works yet the tester file doesn't. I have re uploaded. Thanks again, Rich

Comment: Fixed it! Read the documentation following your link and replaced $ with jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have other JS libraries already included. These libraries are accessed via $, the same way jquery is. If you have to use mutiple libraries use jquery [no conflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help. This does seem to be the issue, but I don't understand what to put in the jQuery("div").hide(); or the $('someid').hide() lines? Thanks, Rich

Comment: @Richard -- Jeff was just giving an example of some jQuery code.